# Creating a sphere that looks like Earth

Tags: textures, texture-mapping, povray

How can you create a sphere in POV-Ray that looks like Earth? Presumably the answer would involve taking some kind of map of Earth and somehow wrapping it around a sphere as a texture. A Google search got me as far as http://www.physics.sfasu.edu/astro/courses/phy315/povray6.html but when I tried following the directions with the supplied files, the result is garbled; the texture doesn't seem to be wrapped correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used povray but a simple google search led to [this page](http://www.midnightkite.com/index.aspx?URL=PlanetRendering) (where you can download the pov-planet sources) and about 2 minutes in the `povray` manpage resulted in

```
povray -Otest -Iplanets-1.pov
```

which in turn produced an `test.png` with some planets.

You can try this as a starting point.

(POV-Ray 3.7.0.1.unofficial @ archlinux 64bit)